# 'numpy.int64' object is not callable when trying to print array

Tags: python, numpy, import

I am getting the error message : 'numpy.int64' object is not callable when trying to print a numpy array. This has never happened before and the error randomly appeared and I have not been able to resolve it.

I have tried restarting my computer. Jupyter notebook printed the array once, then when I ran the code again, the error reappeared.

My code:

```
import networkx as nx  
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

myArray=np.linspace(0,4,4)  
print(myArray)
```

Comment: Does your code create a variable called `print`?

Comment: Yes, and I don't know why or how I can resolve it.

Comment: I also tried opening a new file in jupyter notebook and print() works fine there. Could it be something in the rest of the code within the file?